# Using strcpy() with arrays of structs (and their elements) doesn't work

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct, malloc

Working on a homework assignment but have been stuck on this problem for the past 2 hours. I basically have a struct called `courses`. The struct is defined as so:

```
typedef struct {
  int crn;
  char course[STR_SIZE];
  char course_number[STR_SIZE];
} courses;
```

I have a dynamically allocated array that contains these structs, called `courses_array`. I also have another temp array called `temp_courses_array`. I'm trying to copy the contents of the structs in `courses_array` to the structs in `temp_courses_array` by using `strcpy()`; ie. the `course_number` element in the i-th position of `courses_array` should be copied as the `course_number` element in the i-th position of `temp_courses_array`. For some reason, whenever I invoke the `strcpy()` function, the *same four elements* keep getting copied into `temp_courses_array`. Here's my code (the output is below the code):

```
void resize (int **p_size, courses **courses_array)
{
  int i;
  courses *temp_courses_array;
  **p_size = **p_size*2;

  //Initialize the temp array.
  initialize(p_size, &temp_courses_array);

  printf("----------------BEGIN EXPECTED OUTPUT----------------\n");

  for (i = 0; i < ((**p_size)/2); i++)
  {
    printf("%d %s\n", i, ((*courses_array)[i]).course_number);
  }

  printf("----------------BEGIN ACTUAL OUTPUT------------------\n");

  for (i = 0; i < ((**p_size)/2); i++)
  {
    printf("%d %s\n", i, ((*courses_array)[i]).course_number);
    strcpy((temp_courses_array[i]).course_number, ((*courses_array)[i]).course_number);
  }

  free(*courses_array);
  *courses_array = temp_courses_array;   

}//resize()
```

I'm at a loss as to why this could be happening. It seems that I'm somehow modifying `courses_array` by using the `strcpy()` function... which makes no sense since `strcpy()` should leave the original array intact. Am I correct in this assumption or am I missing anything? I guess another option would be to copy the *entire* struct into the `temp_courses_array` instead of each individual element. I'm not sure how to do that though. If someone could point me in the right direction, that'd be great. Thanks!

Here's the output:

```
--------------BEGIN EXPECTED OUTPUT----------------
//The first element is the iteration in the loop (i).
0 052
1 123
2 170
3 100B
4 100B
5 106
6 106
7 112
8 136
9 171B
10 171B
11 189C
------------BEGIN ACTUAL OUTPUT---------------
//Notice the repeating elements.
0 052
1 123
2 170
3 100B
4 052
5 123
6 170
7 100B
8 052
9 123
10 170
11 100B
```

**EDIT:** Here's my `initialize()` function:

```
void initialize(int **p_size, courses **courses_array)
{ 
  *courses_array = (courses *) malloc((**p_size) * sizeof(courses *));
}//initialize()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything obvious that would cause this.  You should show your `initialize` function.  Perhaps you're messing up or overlapping the two arrays.

I'll answer the second part of your question, because I think that's better for you:

> I guess another option would be to copy the entire struct into the `temp_courses_array` instead of each individual element.

Yes.  Because the struct is plain-old-data (*POD*), you can just copy it like any other inbuilt type:

```
for (i = 0; i < ((**p_size)/2); i++)
{
    temp_courses_array[i] = (*courses_array)[i];
}
```

However, you may still have an issue with `initialize` so you still need to fix it.

---

Note that you don't normally have to do this reallocate-copy-free process.  Instead, you can use `realloc` to resize a block of memory, and it will handle the details.  If it can enlarge the block without copying, it will.  If it needs to create a new one and copy the old one in, it will.

So your function could be as simple as this:

```
void resize (int **p_size, courses **courses_array)
{
    courses *temp = realloc( *courses_array, **p_size * 2 );
    if( temp ) {
        **p_size *= 2;
        *courses_array = temp;
    }
}
```

---

**Follow-up**

Since you posted your `initialize` function...

```
void initialize(int **p_size, courses **courses_array)
{ 
    *courses_array = (courses *) malloc((**p_size) * sizeof(courses *));
}
```

This is allocating an array large enough to hold a bunch of pointers.  Use `sizeof(courses)` instead of `sizeof(courses*)` and it will fix.  Currently you're overflowing your array (because your structure is larger than a pointer) and you are getting *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Yeah, the only reason why I'm not using `realloc` and doing everything manually is because my homework assignment has very strict guidelines/specifications (this one happens to be one of them). I'll try this out and let you know if it works!

Comment: Just posted my `initialize()` function btw. See anything off there?

Comment: Yes, you're making an array of pointers.  Use `sizeof(courses)` instead of `sizeof(courses*)` and it will fix.  Currently you're overflowing your array and getting undefined behaviour.